# How to abort a stash pop?

Tags: git, git-stash

I popped a stash and there was a merge conflict. Unlike the question that is listed as a duplicate, I already had some uncommitted changes in the directory which I wanted to keep. I don't just want to make the merge conflict disappear, but also to get my directory back to the state it was before the pop.

I tried `git merge --abort`, but git claimed no merge was in progress. Is there an easy way to abort a pop without destroying the changes I originally had in the directory?

Comment: As for your uncommited changes: were these changes already in the index?

Comment: Can you post the version of git you are using.

Comment: Did git split your files into  `>>>>>`, `=====`, `<<<<<` for merges?

Comment: See also: [git stash blunder: git stash pop and ended up with merge conflicts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2840816/425313)

Comment: Relevant info from the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2840816/425313): If a conflict occurs, the stash is not dropped from the stash list.

Comment: The accepted answer looks complicated. I think it's pretty good general practice to never do something like attempt `git stash pop` on an unclean working dir. In which case you may simply `git reset --hard` and your stash is still intact. (This is more or less what @BradKoch's linked topic suggests)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo git stash pop that results in merge conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207256/undo-git-stash-pop-that-results-in-merge-conflict)

Comment: @StevenLu, I agree, but the issue can occur in a clean working dir if you're stashing the changes in order to move them to a different branch.  The stash conflicts with commits that exist on the new branch that didn't exist on the old one.

Comment: @Casebash, it's been awhile since this was asked, would you consider revisiting your accepted answer? `git` has progressed enough in the last decade that there is a one-liner solution given in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60444590/4271922.

Comment: @KennSebesta: I've accepted it for now - I'll test it next time I run into this issue

Answer (score 797, accepted):

## Simple one liner

I have always used

`git reset --merge`

I can't remember it ever failing.

---

<sub>Note: `git reset --merge` will discard any staged changes. Also, as noted by @Saroopashree Kumaraguru in the comments, the stash contents won't be lost and can be re-applied later.</sub>

Comment: Give this person a medal

Comment: What happens to the previously stashed content if you do this?  Is it put back on the stash or is it lost?

Comment: It is put back on the stash.

Comment: @AdamParkin When the `git stash pop` is not successful because of merge conflicts, then the stash contents will automatically be stored in the stash instead of deleting it

Comment: IT WORKS! But -- How is this different than `git merge --abort` ? During the bad stash pop/apply git even says "auto-merging...conflict...auto-merging..." and then there's no merge in progress to abort, but there IS one to reset? Ahhh.

Comment: I am getting: "fatal: Cannot do a keep reset in the middle of a merge." using git reset --keep

Comment: This note really needs to be larger. Not losing staged changes was my whole point why I looked for this =/

Comment: @SimonKohlmeyer see where you're coming from, but I respectfully disagree in this context. The note is for an edge case which I have never encountered in 15 years of using git. It is important for a small class of people, though, which is why I added it to my answer. However, giving it the same font unnecessarily scares people who are not intimately familiar with git and able to parse what "staged changes" are. Keeping it small lets people know that it's generally safe to ignore.

Answer (score 367):

My use case: just tried popping onto the wrong branch and got conflicts.  All I need is to undo the pop but keep it in the stash list so I can pop it out on the correct branch.  I did this:

```
git reset HEAD --hard
git checkout my_correct_branch
git stash pop
```

Easy.

Comment: So the stash that you want stays in the stash list until you have a successful pop?

Comment: This is not an answer for original question as it would wipe local changes which were not committed.

Comment: @RyanClark See [DavidG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13338764/4213607) below. Basically, yes, it stays in the stash list.

Comment: I think the vast majority of users who find themselves in this situation will find this solution to be ideal. I can't imagine a situation where I have uncommitted changes in my working directory before attempting to `stash pop` into it. That sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Nice.  After reading this I looked at git stash pop docs and it says "Applying the state can fail with conflicts; in this case, it is not removed from the stash list.".  So, this is why the stash is able to be re-popped after a reset / checkout.

Comment: Wipe out all the local changes _you want to keep_. Easy. XD

Comment: Don't do this or you will lose all uncommitted changes in the directory. Misleading upvotes !!!!

Answer (score 67):

Ok, I think I have worked out "git stash unapply".  It's more complex than `git apply --reverse` because you need reverse merging action in case there was any merging done by the `git stash apply`.

The reverse merge requires that all current changes be pushed into the index:

- `git add -u`

Then invert the `merge-recursive` that was done by `git stash apply`:

- `git merge-recursive stash@{0}: -- $(git write-tree) stash@{0}^1`

Now you will be left with just the non-stash changes.  They will be in the index.  You can use `git reset` to unstage your changes if you like.

Given that your original `git stash apply` failed I assume the reverse might also fail since some of the things it wants to undo did not get done.

Here's an example showing how the working copy (via `git status`) ends up clean again:

```
 $ git status
# On branch trunk
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
 $ git stash apply
Auto-merging foo.c
# On branch trunk
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   foo.c
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
 $ git add -u
 $ git merge-recursive stash@{0}: -- $(git write-tree) stash@{0}^1
Auto-merging foo.c
 $ git status
# On branch trunk
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: after doing this, will the previously stashed edits be lost forever, or are they back in the stash?

Comment: `git stash apply` never drops a stash, and when a merge fails then `git stash pop` also retains the stash

Comment: Bad things will happen if there was a merge conflict during the original stash pop

Comment: Keep scrolling for better answers

Answer (score 53):

Edit: From the `git help stash` documentation in the pop section:

Applying the state can fail with conflicts; in this case, it is not removed from the stash list. You need to resolve the conflicts by hand and call git stash drop manually afterwards.

If the --index option is used, then tries to reinstate not only the working tree's changes, but also the index's ones. However, this can fail, when you have conflicts (which are stored in the index, where you therefore can no longer apply the changes as they were originally).

Try hardcopying all your repo into a new dir (so you have a copy of it) and run:

`git stash show` and save that output somewhere if you care about it.

then: `git stash drop` to drop the conflicting stash
then: `git reset HEAD`

That should leave your repo in the state it was before (hopefully, I still haven't been able to repro your problem)

===

I am trying to repro your problem but all I get when usin `git stash pop` is:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
...
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

In a clean dir:

```
git init
echo hello world > a
git add a & git commit -m "a"
echo hallo welt >> a
echo hello world > b
git add b & git commit -m "b"
echo hallo welt >> b
git stash
echo hola mundo >> a
git stash pop
```

I don't see git trying to merge my changes, it just fails. Do you have any repro steps we can follow to help you out?

Comment: Try stashing changes to a different file.

Comment: Trying to stash to a different file didn't work (see new repro steps). I just can't repro the issue...

Comment: This solution does not work if there are uncommitted changes in the working directory.

Comment: @here This is not a real solution, this is just to show that I can't reproduce the problem the OP has and that he hasn't provided any steps to get to where he is at.

Comment: @DavidG -- [maybe this?](https://gist.github.com/here/4f3af6dafdb4ca15e804), comments appreciated :).

Comment: Actual scenario is: 1) Change file A. 2) Stash changes 3) Make Conflicting change in file A and commit (e.g. change same line) 4) Change file B 5) Do 'git stash pop'. Now you have conflict and local changes. Generally they will be in different files, but you will never know which non-conflicting modified files from stash and which are local unstaged changes.

Comment: This only helped me to remove some of my stahed files, which is certainly not what I intended. Do not try this(git stash drop) if you don't want to lose some of your srashed files

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have to worry about any other changes you made and you just want to go back to the last commit, then you can do:

```
git reset .
git checkout .
git clean -f
```

Answer (score 5):

OK, I think I have managed to find a work-flow that will get you back to where you need to be (as if you had not done the pop).

TAKE A BACKUP BEFOREHAND!! I don't know whether this will work for you, so copy your whole repo just in case it doesn't work.

1) Fix the merge problems and fix all the conflict by selecting all the changes that come from the patch (in tortoisemerge, this shows up as one.REMOETE (theirs)).

```
git mergetool
```

2) Commit these changes (they will already be added via the mergetool command). Give it a commit message of "merge" or something you remember.

```
git commit -m "merge"
```

3) Now you will still have your local unstaged changes that you started originally, with a new commit from the patch (we can get rid of this later). Now commit your unstaged changes

```
git add .
git add -u .
git commit -m "local changes"
```

4) Reverse the patch. This can be done with the following command:

```
git stash show -p | git apply -R
```

5) Commit these changes:

```
git commit -a -m "reversed patch"
```

6) Get rid of the patch/unpatch commits

```
git rebase -i HEAD^^^
```

from this, remove the two lines with 'merge' and 'reversed patch' in it.

7) Get your unstanged changes back and undo the 'local changes' commit

```
git reset HEAD^
```

I've run through it with a simple example and it gets you back to where you want to be - directly before the stash was popped, with your local changes and with the stash still being available to pop.

Comment: If that doesn't quite work, hopefully it'll get you most of the way there! :-)

Comment: `git stash show -p | git apply -R` that doesn't work if the `git stash apply` did any real merging.  See my answer...

Answer (score 4):

I solved this in a somewhat different way. Here's what happened.

First, I popped on the wrong branch and got conflicts. The stash remained intact but the index was in conflict resolution, blocking many commands.

A simple `git reset HEAD` aborted the conflict resolution and left the uncommitted (and **UNWANTED**) changes.

Several `git co <filename>` reverted the index to the initial state. Finally, I switched branch with `git co <branch-name>` and run a new `git stash pop`, which resolved without conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:

- Use `git mergetool` to split the merge files into original and new parts. Hopefully one of those is the file with your non-stash changes in it.
- Apply the diff of the stash in reverse, to undo just those changes. You'll probably have to manually split out the files with the merge conflicts (which hopefully the above trick will work for).

I didn't test either of these, so I don't know for sure of they will work.

Answer (score 3):

If you just have the stashed changes try this 1 liner. It removes every local change present.

**git checkout -f**

Answer (score 3):

Merge --abort only when you merge other branch code and it has conflict.

```
git merge --abort
```

If stash pop has conflict, you can use:

```
git reset --merge
```

Answer (score 2):

I could reproduce clean `git stash pop` on "dirty" directory, with uncommitted changes, but not yet pop that generates a merge conflict.

**If** on merge conflict the stash you tried to apply didn't disappear, you can try to examine `git show stash@{0}` (optionally with `--ours` or `--theirs`) and compare with `git statis` and `git diff HEAD`.  You should be able to see which changes came from applying a stash.

Answer (score 2):

If DavidG is correct that it didn't pop the stash because of the merge conflict, then you merely need to clean up your working directory.  Quickly `git commit` everything you care about.  (You can `reset` or `squash` the commit later if you're not done.)  Then with everything you care about safe, `git reset` everything else that `git stash pop` dumped into your working directory.

Answer (score 2):

If there were no staged changes before the `git stash pop`, as in the question, then the following two commands should work.

```
git diff --name-only --cached | xargs git checkout --ours HEAD
git ls-tree stash@{0}^3 --name-only | xargs rm
```

The first reverses any merges from the stash, successful or not.  The second deletes any untracked files introduced by the stash.

From `man git stash` : `The working directory must match the index.`  Which @DavidG points out, the `stash pop` will fail if any currently unstaged modified files conflict.  As such, we shouldn't need to worry about unwinding merge conflicts beyond getting back to `HEAD`.  Any remaining modified files are then unrelated to the stash, and were modified before the `stash pop`

If there were staged changes, I'm unclear on whether we can rely on the same commands and you may want to try @Ben Jackson's technique.  Suggestions appreciated..

Here is a testing setup for all of the various cases https://gist.github.com/here/4f3af6dafdb4ca15e804

```
# Result:
# Merge succeeded in m (theirs)
# Conflict in b
# Unstaged in a
# Untracked in c and d

# Goal:
# Reverse changes to successful merge m
# Keep our version in merge conflict b
# Keep our unstaged a
# Keep our untracked d
# Delete stashed untracked c
```

Comment: I think this is the most correct answer so far. Very well thought out.

Answer (score 1):

Try using if tracked file.

```
git rm <path to file>
git reset  <path to file>
git checkout <path to file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `git reflog` to list all changes made in your git history. Copy an action id and type `git reset ACTION_ID`

Comment: Git doesn't create a reflog entry before you pop (you need to have a commit)

Answer (score -2):

I'm posting here hoping that others my find my answer helpful. I had a similar problem when I tried to do a stash pop on a different branch than the one I had stashed from. On my case I had no files that were uncommitted or in the index but still got into the merge conflicts case (same case as @pid). As others pointed out previously, the failed git stash pop did indeed retain my stash, then A quick git reset HEAD plus going back to my original branch and doing the stash from there did resolve my problem.